# VeeValidate: "errors" does not exist in template

Tags: vue.js, symfony-3.4, vee-validate

I'm trying to use VeeValidate to validate fields in a Vue form using Vue 2.5 and VeeValidate 2.1. Following the documentation, I'm validating a field like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
name="contact-email"
id="contact-email"
type="email"
v-model="contact-email"  
v-validate="'required|email'"
>
<span v-if="errors.has('contact-email')">{{ errors.first('contact-email') }}</span>
```

This throws an error: `Variable "errors" does not exist.` This would imply that VeeValidate was not properly installed.

VeeValidate was installed using `yarn add vee-validate` and added at the top of the js file, before any other Vue code, like this:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

Update: 
When I remove the `span` line that throws the error and examine this Vue instance using the Vue browser plugin (which shows all propertied and their values), I see that VeeValidate has automatically added two computed properties, `errors` and `fields`. 
Both are objects that look like this:

```
errors = { items: Array[0] }
fields = { student-contact-email: { changed: false, dirty: false, invalid: true, pending: false, pristine: true, required: true, touched: false,
untouched: true, valid: false, validated: false }}
```

I don't understand why `errors` is present as a computed property and yet can't be found in the template.

Answer (score 1):

I see name data in v-model is "contact-email" but errors.has call "email" :

```
<span v-if="errors.has('email')">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
```

I think you should fix:

```
<span v-if="errors.has('contact-email')">{{ errors.first('contact-email') }}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. The variable names are actually correct in my code, but I had a mistake in the post. I edited the post to fix the mistake and to add an update.